# What's the correct way to apply patch for a list in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-mvc, rest

We're using the Marvin.JsonPatch nuget package to do patch in our webservices. I'm currently using this style which seems to work but I'm not sure how to only update a specific object value in the list.
This is the documentation I'm currently following 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/jsonpatch?view=aspnetcore-3.1

```
[
    {
        "op": "replace",
        "path": "/dataDefinitions/0",
        "value": {"name": "Test Name 004", "description": "Test", "dataTypeID": 25}
    }
]
```

However according to this documentation http://jsonpatch.com/,
I should be able to use this style to update only specific values but I'm getting an error along the lines of "Value for argument 'path' is not valid: '/dataDefinitions/0/name'".

```
[
        {
            "op": "replace",
            "path": "/dataDefinitions/0/name",
            "value": "Test Name 1"
    }
]
```

Any ideas? Thanks!